# Converting a for loop into MIPS (printing the inner loop counter)

Tags: assembly, mips, nested-loops

I want to convert this Java code into MIPS:

this is the java code i want to convert

```
for (int i = rows; i >= 1; i--) 
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(j+" ");
        }
        
        System.out.println();
    }
```

and this is my MIPS code so far

```
    .data
    msg1:   .asciiz "\n"
    
    .text
    addi $t0,$t0,6 #t0 = 5
    
loop1:  ble $t0,0,exit 
    subi $t0,$t0,1
    
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, msg1
    syscall
loop2:  
    addi $t1,$t1,1
    
    bgt $t1,$t0,loop1 

    li $v0,1 #printing int 
    move $a0,$t1
    syscall
    
    
    li $v0,11
    la $a0,' '
    syscall
    j loop2
    

    exit:
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

it keeps giving me this output: "1 2 3 4 5"

Comment: I assume `$t1` is meant to be `j`, where do you initialize it?

Comment: i didn't i just assumed it will be zero and will be incremented

Comment: That may work the first time, but after that it's not zero any more

Comment: I initialized now to 1, now the output is : 2 3 4 5

Comment: You hace to initialize t1 each time you reach the inner loop. Just before loop2.

Comment: Thank you Sir! my program works just fine now

Answer (score -1):

In the inner loop the condition compares `t1` and `t0`, so the first time the loop works fine. But then the value in `t1` remains 5 or 6 therefore the condition becomes false and every time it jumps back to loop1 and print `msg1`.

```
.data

msg1:   .asciiz "\n"

.text
main:
addi $t0,$t0,6 


loop1:  
    ble $t0,0,exit 
    sub $t0, $t0, 1

    li $v0,4
    la $a0, msg1
    syscall
    li $t1, 0 # This was missing. You have to reinitialize t1 every time before the inner loop starts
loop2:  
    addi $t1,$t1,1

    bgt $t1,$t0,loop1 

    li $v0,1 #printing int 
    move $a0,$t1
    syscall


    li $v0,11
    la $a0,' '
    syscall
    j loop2


    exit:
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

Comment: In the inner loop the condition compares t1 and t0, so the first time the loop works fine. But then the value in t1 remains 5 or 6 therefore the condition becomes false and every time it jumps back to loop1 and print msg1.